# Adding a multiple Image gallery to a page with text?

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm learning Wagtail and I'm trying to make a basic Ecommerce style site. The layout will be:

```
Home Page
 -> Products
    -> Product 1
    -> ...
    -> Product N
 -> About 
 -> Contact
```

In the Product page I want to have a Title, Description, Picture gallery or just display a few pictures and eventually tags (But this post is about the Images). I have checked this [Documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.10.2/advanced_topics/images/custom_image_model.html) which explain how to add Abstract Images in the View but it leaves me confused on what to import and add to the model, what type? when I just want to add 1,2...n Images on a Product page. The documentation only explains how to add an Image into a form and it leaves me wondering should I use a Django type or Wagtail type?

How would I add the ability to upload/remove images from the admin console Product page?

Comment: This is covered by the tutorial section of the docs: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html#images

Comment: Ahh, So it is, my bad! If you post this as a reply I will mark it as the correct answer.